# Cannot locate Rx Tx pins on SIM800a GSM module

Tags: arduino-due, gsm

I recently bought a SIM800a GSM module in India and I am unable to find the Rx Tx pins of the module to make calls using a Arduino duimilanove.

The main problem is also that I can't find the data sheet for Sim800a in the net so that I can use a multi meter to determine the Rx Tx pins.

Here are some screenshots of the module-

[image: Top View showing 4 unlabeled pins compare with the labelled picture on the net]
[image: Side View 1]
[image: Side View 2]

There is no label showing Rx Tx here. There is I2C protocol(SCL,SDA) but I dont know how to code in Arduino for making a call using I2C.

I found a SIM800a picture on ebay with labels(not the data sheet) but when I tried using the pins in that manner it did not work. The SIM800a I have is connected to the network as the network led blinks after 3 sec and when I call it then the alarm rings. But it is unable to transmit calls or sms.

[image: labelled sim800a]

This is the code I am using. I remove the Rx Tx pins before uploading the code and immediately put them after uploading.

```
char phone_no[]="9953642386";
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);  //Open Serial Connection at baudrate 9600
delay(5000);
Serial.println("AT"); // Wake up GSM
Serial.print("ATD"); //Dial the phone number using ATD command
Serial.print(phone_no);
Serial.println(";"); // Semicolon is a must at the end
delay(5000);
Serial.println("ATH"); // After a delay of 5 secs Hang the call
}
void loop()
{
// empty loop.If you enter the above code here,the call will be made FOR EVER repeatedly.
//Take Caution while coding under loop.At some condition you’ve to terminate the Call
}
```

Otherwise is it possible to use the SDA and SCL pins for this purpose of calling to a phone from the gsm module ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This datasheet](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800/SIM800_Hardware%20Design_V1.08.pdf) may help you.  On page 14 you can see TXD and RXD are pins 9 and 10.

Orientation is hard to determine, but it appears that pin 1 is where the most red on the label is.

[image]
You should now be able to trace where those pins go to. They look like they go to high numbered pins, around the 11/12 area.

Comment: Thanks found the pins :) didnt realize the data sheet of sim 800a and sim 800 will be the same